# Combining Multiple Workbooks Into One Workbook Worksheet With Powershell

Tags: excel, powershell

I have this Powershell script i'm trying to combine multiple workbooks with single sheets onto one workbook with a single sheet and combine them all on the one sheet.  I can't get past the fact it keeps telling me there is no file named $destfile and can't be opened.  What is the correct syntax for that?

Thanks

```
$ExcelObject = New-Object -ComObject excel.application
$ExcelObject.visible=$true
$file1 = 'file1location'
$file2 = 'file2location'
$destfile = 'fileI want to saveas afterits compiled'

$xl = new-object -c excel.application
$xl.displayAlerts = $false # don't prompt the user
$wb1 = $xl.workbooks.open($file1, $null, $true) # open source, readonly
$wb2 = $xl.workbooks.open($file2, $null, $true)
$wb3 = $xl.workbooks.open($destfile) # open target
$sh1_wb2 = $wb2.sheets.item(1) # first sheet in destination workbook
$sheetToCopy = $wb1.sheets.item('Sheet1') # source sheet to copy
$sheetToCopy.copy($sh1_wb2) # copy source sheet to destination workbook
$wb1.close($false) # close source workbook w/o saving
$wb2.close($true) # close and save destination workbook
$xl.quit()
spps -n excel
```

Comment: Does the file described by `$destfile` exist?

Comment: No I need to create a new one daily.

Comment: You're trying to open a non-existing file in `$wb3 = $xl.workbooks.open($destfile)`

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use https://github.com/dfinke/ImportExcel
Export data to csv from multiple worksheets with Import-CSV, then combine those CSV files (i suppose that they have identical rows) and import combined CVS back to excel using Export-CSV... quite simple. and does not require any COM manipulations.